# How to hdf5 (Hdfsl ) file (One Column Read) read (Big Size file)

Tags: hdf5, hdfql

I am using the HDF5DotNet with C# and I can read only full data as the attached image in the dataset. 
The hdf5 file is too big, up to nearly 1.4GB, and if I load the whole array into the memory then it will be out of memory.

I would like to read all data from One columns

```
double[] values = new double[203572];

string m_Doc_01 = "data/sample/line";

HDFql.Execute("USE DIRECTORY " + "\"" + File_Directory + "\""); 
HDFql.Execute("USE FILE " + "\"" + File_Name + "\"");
HDFql.Execute("CREATE CHUNKED(1, 203572) DATASET my_dataset_BS AS DOUBLE(2050, 203572)");
```

How to "m_Doc_01 ==> my_dataset_BS" Data
???
???

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2050; i++)
    {
      HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM " + "\"" + m_Doc_01 + "\"" + "(1:::1)  INTO MEMORY " + HDFql.VariableRegister(values));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question so it will be readable.

Answer (score 0):

To read the column that you have highlighted in the screenshot (i.e. column #0), you have to change the hyperslab to (please note the 0):

```
HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM " + "\"" + m_Doc_01 + "\"" + "[, 0:::1]  INTO MEMORY " + HDFql.VariableRegister(values));
```

That said, if you want to loop through the dataset and read one column at the time do the following (also better to register variable `values` before the loop starts and unregister it after the loop is done - this will increase performance):

```
number = HDFql.VariableRegister(values);

for(int i = 0; i < 2050; i++)
{ 
    HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM " + "\"" + m_Doc_01 + "\"" + "[, " + i + ":::1]  INTO MEMORY " + number);

    // do something with variable "values" (which contains the values of column #i)
}

HDFql.VariableUnregister(values);
```

Comment: SELECT FROM "data/sample/line"(0:::1) INTO MEMORY 0

Error message ( -99 )

HDFQL_ERROR_UNKNOWN
Represents an operation that failed due to an
unknown/unexpected error

However, Low capacity files do not have errors. < 500 MB or less >

Comment: Could you turn on the debug mechanism (by executing operation `SET DEBUG ENABLE` in HDFql) and post here the output when you execute the operation that gives you an HDFQL_ERROR_UNKNOWN?

Comment: script message <SELECT FROM "data/sample/line"(0:::1)  INTO MEMORY 0>
Error Message <Error when reading data from object "data/sample/line" >

Comment: "Among the sample files I have "
Error Count Row < 74470 , 79800 , 203572 , 259748 >
// No Error Count Row < 564 , 2701 , 2714 , 10366 , 10367 >